# Python script to move files based on date and partition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to create a python script which can take a date to move file from one s3 folder to another s3 folder. Now while moving it uses created date to create folder in target i.e. stage/2023/01/12 and copy the file to this new folder.
Thanks
Param

I have used boto3 but not sure how to achieve that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the modification or creation date of each file, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-do-i-get-file-creation-and-modification-date-times?rq=1). It explains how to get the modification or creation date (returned as POSIX timestamp, i.e. seconds from the Unix epoch, January 1 1970).

You'll likely want to make the POSIX timestamp easier to work with by using the [python datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-date); you'll begin by converting to a datetime object with `date.fromtimestamp(your_posix_timestamp_here)`

To programmatically create folders for year, month, and day, and copy the file to that folder: First pull the year, month, and day out of the datetime object, then do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from pathlib import Path
Path('2023/01/12/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # make nested folders for year, month, day
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "2023/01/12/file.foo") # move the file
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The innocuous-looking "s3" in the question means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3 - so nothing applies here what you can do in a local filesystem.